# Auto generate dimen.xml in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have builded all layouts with hardcoded values(paddings, measures and e.t.).
Is there any way to automatically transfer values to dimen.xml?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: you can set Dimen.xml file for all resolution.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want he to automatically formed from layouts.

Comment: thats we can do but for that you have set custom font size of each text, it is better to set Dimen for each resolution with its folder name.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,
You can't generate the dimen.xml for hardcorded project automatically. You need to manually create the dimen.xml file for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi as per your need and use that dimen reference instead of the hardcoded values. There is no other way to do it.